# Ascending order of results in sparql by using nonnegative integers that come as strings

Tags: sparql, rdf, triplestore, graphdb

I have more than 2000 resources in my triple store (GraphDB) that I would like to sort in ascending order, based on their IRI, whereas the IRI looks like:

```
http://TABLE/240b9f63-66b9-47f1-9e02-bfd03794bbd9#1
http://TABLE/240b9f63-66b9-47f1-9e02-bfd03794bbd9#2
http://TABLE/240b9f63-66b9-47f1-9e02-bfd03794bbd9#3
...
http://TABLE/240b9f63-66b9-47f1-9e02-bfd03794bbd9#2345
```

In my graph, all abovementioned IRIs are connected to one resource by "DE6:complex_Data_Type_has_Member". In order to get all the abovementioned IRIs I do the following:

```
PREFIX DE6: <http://DE6/DINEN61360#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>

SELECT ?IRIs_to_Sort WHERE{
         ?Array a DE6:Data_Element;
         DE6:complex_Data_Type_has_Member ?IRIs_to_Sort .


} ORDER BY ?IRIs_to_Sort
```

If I just use the "ORDER BY ?IRIs_to_Sort" solution sequence modifier, where as shown in https://www.w3.org/TR/2013/REC-sparql11-query-20130321/#modOrderBy

then I get the following result (only first ten reults are shown):

```
http://TABLE/240b9f63-66b9-47f1-9e02-bfd03794bbd9#1
http://TABLE/240b9f63-66b9-47f1-9e02-bfd03794bbd9#10
http://TABLE/240b9f63-66b9-47f1-9e02-bfd03794bbd9#100
http://TABLE/240b9f63-66b9-47f1-9e02-bfd03794bbd9#1000
http://TABLE/240b9f63-66b9-47f1-9e02-bfd03794bbd9#1001
http://TABLE/240b9f63-66b9-47f1-9e02-bfd03794bbd9#1002
http://TABLE/240b9f63-66b9-47f1-9e02-bfd03794bbd9#1003
http://TABLE/240b9f63-66b9-47f1-9e02-bfd03794bbd9#1004
http://TABLE/240b9f63-66b9-47f1-9e02-bfd03794bbd9#1005
http://TABLE/240b9f63-66b9-47f1-9e02-bfd03794bbd9#1006
...
http://TABLE/240b9f63-66b9-47f1-9e02-bfd03794bbd9#1999
http://TABLE/240b9f63-66b9-47f1-9e02-bfd03794bbd9#2
http://TABLE/240b9f63-66b9-47f1-9e02-bfd03794bbd9#20
http://TABLE/240b9f63-66b9-47f1-9e02-bfd03794bbd9#200
http://TABLE/240b9f63-66b9-47f1-9e02-bfd03794bbd9#2000
http://TABLE/240b9f63-66b9-47f1-9e02-bfd03794bbd9#2001
http://TABLE/240b9f63-66b9-47f1-9e02-bfd03794bbd9#2002
http://TABLE/240b9f63-66b9-47f1-9e02-bfd03794bbd9#2003
...
```

Instead, I would expect something like:

```
http://TABLE/240b9f63-66b9-47f1-9e02-bfd03794bbd9#1
http://TABLE/240b9f63-66b9-47f1-9e02-bfd03794bbd9#2
http://TABLE/240b9f63-66b9-47f1-9e02-bfd03794bbd9#3
http://TABLE/240b9f63-66b9-47f1-9e02-bfd03794bbd9#4
...
http://TABLE/240b9f63-66b9-47f1-9e02-bfd03794bbd9#2099
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: The order is lexicofraphical since there is no other way to compare IRIs. One way to workaround is to use what's after the `#`, incase all IRIs follow the same scheme, then convert that to some number and use that in `ORDER BY`. e.g. `order by (xsd:long(strafter(str(?IRIs_to_Sort), "#"))) `

Comment: That solved the issue, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IRIs are treated as lexical values for `ORDER BY`, which means that the numbers in your fragment ids are treated as text, and they are not considered on their own.

A full `ORDER BY` that I think will work for you, whether your result set includes one or many IRIs with one or many frag-IDs each, but *only if all frag-IDs are numeric*, would be --

```
ORDER BY ( xsd:string ( STRBEFORE ( STR ( ?IRIs_to_Sort ), "#" ) ) )
         ( xsd:long ( STRAFTER ( STR ( ?IRIs_to_Sort ), "#" ) ) )
```

If your frag-IDs are a blend of numeric and alphanumeric, things get rather more complicated.